# how to run a function only for the clicked element and not for the whole class

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, resize

I am looking for a way to resize **individually** several div on a page (like a browser window, that you can resize from a bottom corner), keeping the same proportions/ratio. I made the code work for a class .handle and .dragger, but all the div with the same class are being modified at the same time, while I would like it to be executed **only for the div we click on**.

Here is the code to resize that I'm working with:

```
    $(".handle").bind('mousedown', draggerDown);
    $("body").bind('mouseup', draggerUp);

    function calculateNewSize(size) {
        // {currHeight, currWidth, newHeight, newWidth, offsetX, offsetY}
        
        var newWidth;
        var newHeight;

        if (Math.abs(size.offsetX) > Math.abs(size.offsetY)) {
            newWidth = size.currWidth + size.offsetX;
            newHeight = newWidth * (size.currHeight / size.currWidth);
        } else {
            newHeight = size.currHeight + size.offsetY;
            newWidth = newHeight * (size.currWidth / size.currHeight);
        }

        return {
            "height": newHeight,
            "width": newWidth
        };
    }

    function draggerDown() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        currentX = event.pageX;
        currentY = event.pageY;
        
        currentHeight = $(".dragger").height();
        currentWidth = $(".dragger").width();

        $("body").bind('mousemove', draggerMove);
    }

    function draggerMove() {
        var draggerElements = document.getElementsByClassName("dragger");
        for (var n = 0; n < draggerElements.length; ++n) {

        var targetStyle = window.getComputedStyle(draggerElements[n], null);
        var newHeight = currentHeight + (event.pageY - currentY);
        var newWidth = currentWidth + (event.pageX - currentX);
        
        // AT THIS POINT, THE LOGIC COMES IN.
        // CUSTOMIZE 'calculateNewSize' function above

        var newSize = calculateNewSize({
            "currHeight": currentHeight,
            "currWidth": currentWidth,
            "newHeight": newHeight,
            "newWidth": newWidth,
            "offsetX": (event.pageX - currentX),
            "offsetY": (event.pageY - currentY)
        });
        
        currentHeight = newSize.height;
        currentWidth = newSize.width;
        
        newHeight = newSize.height;
        newWidth = newSize.width;

        // AT THIS POINT, THE LOGIC IS DONE.
        // SIZES SHOULD BE COOL NOW

        $(".dragger").css("height", newHeight + "px");
        $(".dragger").css("width", newWidth + "px");
        
        console.log($(".dragger").height());

        currentX = event.pageX;
        currentY = event.pageY;
    }
    }
    function draggerUp() {
        $("body").unbind('mousemove');
    }


      // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
      if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
        window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
          height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
          slug: "xUAZ5"
        }], "*")
      }

      // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
      window.name = "result"
}
```

I am trying to do it with that methodology (from another project) but I don't really know if it could work with the previous code:

```
var u; 

for(var i=1; i<13; i++) {
    var specificClass= document.getElementsByClassName("class"+i);

    for (u = 0; u < specificClass.length; u++) {
        specificClass[u].addEventListener("click", thefunction);
    }
}

function thefunction(evenement) {
//    alert(evenement.target.classList)
    var clickedElement = document.getElementsByClassName(evenement.target.classList);
    for (u = 0; u < clickedElement.length; u++) {
        clickedElement[u].style etc.
    }
}
```

In that case I would these two groups of class: handle1, handle2, handle3,... and  dragger1, dragger2, dragger3...

Here is my simplified html body:

```
<div class="draggableDiv dragger div1">
  <div class="handle"></div>
</div>

<div class="draggableDiv dragger div2">
  <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

Any other methodology is very welcomed of course, this is only what I've been trying :)
Let me know if you would need more details
Thanks!

Comment: You keep using `$(".dragger")` in your functions, this targets all elements that have the class. If the event listeners are properly set up, you can use `$(this)` to target only the current element. Alternatively, you have to store it in an external variable after the click and use that variable to resize the element.

Comment: ok thanks! Do you have some advices to properly set up the event listeners to use `$(this)`? I don't really know how to move on from what I have

Comment: You're binding the mousedown listener to `.handle`, so I guess you need `$(this).closest('.dragger')` or something (i.e. walk up the DOM tree from the clicked handle to it's dragger parent)

Comment: should I replace all the `$(".dragger")` with that?

Comment: You can try that, yes. But without seeing the HTML, ideally as [mre], I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I now added my html body (not the css but let me know if that would help).  Just replacing all the `$(".dragger")` by `$(this).closest('.dragger')`is not working for now

Comment: Alright, got it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kr1h5tzx/

Comment: amazing! thanks a lot it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: sorry to reactivate the post, but in the meantime I've been facing a small problem about the ratio, I've updated your fiddle: <https://jsfiddle.net/ap1b6wtc/2/> : I have the blue element (which is an image in my "real" code) and at the top a white line with a height of 20px -> the latter gets heigher when the div is resized and I wished it would stay the same (=20px). I've tried things but no good result. Any clues?

Comment: Hey, just use padding instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bds8g6wt/

Comment: aah so easy, thanks again!! all good now!